# Android photo picker for lollipop and above

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, photo, picker

I'm using the following code for picking photos:

```
Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

and return the result with following:

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

This works good on pre-lollipop but it says "Unfortunately the app has stopped" on lollipop and above. Do I need any permissions on lollipop and above? Has something changed since lollipop? Please guide me/ Suggest a simple method to pick photos on lollipop and above.

Answer (score 1):

Use following way

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, Const.PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

OR use custom layout and activity

I have developed it.Please check below link working in all android version 4.0 or above. you dont need to ask for permission as its target version is 22.
https://github.com/rajscet/Photo_Picker_Git

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need any permissions on lollipop and above?

You should hold `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Note that on Android 6.0+, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you need to use runtime permissions to request this permission from the user, as these permissions are `dangerous`.

Comment: I'll try with the permissions but two questions: Why does it work without permissions on pre lollipop? and the above code opens gallery app but stops while returning results, can it do so without these permissions?

Comment: @HasaanAhmed: "Why does it work without permissions on pre lollipop?" -- you should be having the same problem on Android 4.4. On Android 4.3 and below, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` either did not exist or was not enforced. "and the above code opens gallery app but stops while returning results, can it do so without these permissions?" -- I am sorry, but I do not understand this question.